# Can we edit the IIS 401.2 access denied page content?

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, http-status-code-401

This might be a silly question but I was wondering if we can edit the contents of the standard 401.2 access denied page. In an ideal situation, this page should not come up.

[image: 401.2 page]

I tried editing the custom error page listed in IIS (401-2.htm), but the HTML there is different than what is being shown on this page.

One way could be to show a custom error page instead of the standard page, but I am just curious about this.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I am using IIS 6.0

**Edit**: To add more to the context, the requirement that I have is basically to remove the .NET version information that is showing up at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!  There is a tab for custom errors under site properties.  You'll just have to name your file according to the appropriate error code.

Here is a Microsoft article that shows you in detail how to do it:

https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/80cb8d8d-8fd8-4af5-bb3b-4d11fff3ab9c.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info, but as already mentioned by me in the post, I tried editing the page, but its of no use. The html on the 401-2.htm page, which is in the custom errors list mentioned in the link, is different from the yellow screen error.

Comment: so what happens when you add a file named "401-2?  I've done this before in IIS 7 and no issues.

Comment: When I add a custom 401-2 file, the original white error page that comes up on access denied error, changes. However, this yellow page still remains the same.

Comment: what do you mean by yellow page?

Comment: My bad. Here. http://static.spiceworks.com/attachments/post/0014/6313/infonet_hszuyd_nl.jpg 
This is the page I was talking about that is editable from the custom errors section. The Yellow page I am referring to is the one that I have posted. Its from IIS 6.0. Hope I make myself clear.

Comment: Technically, you are correct. The standard error page IS editable from the custom error section. The image I have posted in the question is not the standard one. Rather, it is .NET version specific. :) I will edit the question so that its clear. My mistake.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I know what's going on.  You have to edit the <customerrors defaultredirect="yourfile"> in web.config  Have you tried this already?

Comment: Yup. Was about to mention that only. Changing the customerrrors configuration resolved the issue. Thanks for you help. :)